# Unable to access site in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been using: `docker build -t devstack .`

`docker run --rm -p 443:443 -it -v ~/code:/code devstack`

That has been working fine for me so far. I've been able to access the site as expected through my browser. I set my hosts file to point devstack.com to 127.0.0.1 and the site loads nicely. Now I'm trying to use docker-compose so I can use some of the functionality there to more easily connect with AWS.

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "443"
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - ~/code:/code
    image: devstack:latest
```

So I run `docker-compose build` which gives me the familiar build stuff from Dockerfile.
Then I run `docker-compose run web` which puts me into the VM where I start apache (doing it manually at the moment), hit `top` to verify it’s running, then tail the log files. But when I attempt to hit the site in my browser, I get: `devstack.com refused to connect.` and no logs in the apache log files, so it's not even getting to apache. So something about the ports isn't opening up to me. Any idea what I need to change to make this work?

Edit: Updated file. Still same problem:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
#    Same issue with both of these:
#    network_mode: "bridge"
#    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ~/code:/code
    tty: true
```

Comment: what is the URL you open in the browser?

Comment: https://devstack.com. It's set in my hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1

Comment: You're mapping the ports randomly so you need to add the port number in the URL. Probably you are not doing that. Check the mapped port first and enter it in the URL (it will be something like `http://devstack.com:32522`): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/#show-all-mapped-ports

Comment: Or map a container port to a specific port (to map container's port #80 to host's port #80 put `- "80:80"` in the `ports` section).

Comment: Same deal with that one. Updated what I have currently. docker-compose ps shows `webserver_web_run_e94c36a00e20   /bin/sh   Up `. I can enter the server with docker-compose run. curl localhost and I get a result back. So seems all I'm missing is making those ports available to the outside world.

Comment: I also tried adding the --service-ports flag on docker-compose run. Same deal. When I run the older method I was using (just docker run I mentioned above), I did a port scan, and the 443 port is being used and I can access docker. With docker-compose, port scan shows it open. So it's definitely not mapping to docker for some reason.

Comment: Please post the output of `docker version`

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the `docker-compose run web` part. Please try `docker-compose up web` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it working. I used the example project docker-compose showed in their documentation, which runs a test app on port 5000. That worked, so I knew it could be done.

I updated my docker-compose.yml to be very similar to the one in the test project. So it looks like this now:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ~/code:/code
```

Then I created an entry.sh file which will start apache, and added this to my Dockerfile:

```
# copy the entry file which will start apache
COPY entry.sh entry.sh
RUN chmod +x entry.sh

# start apache
CMD ./entry.sh; tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log
```

So now when I do `docker-compose up`, it will start apache and tail the apache log files. So I immediately see apache log files output to terminal. Then I'm able to access the site. Basically the problem was just with the VM exiting. This was the only way I could find to keep it from exiting without doing tty=true in the docker-compose, which while it kept it from exiting, wouldn't publish the ports.